# Prove that the symmetric group $S_n$ has a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_7 \times \mathbb{Z}_7$ iff $n \ge 14$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, direct-product

> I want to prove that the symmetric group $S_n$ has a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_7 \times \mathbb{Z}_7$ iff $n \ge 14$.

One direction seems clear. |$\mathbb{Z}_7 \times \mathbb{Z}_7| = 49$, and the factorizations of $49$ are $49*1$ and $7*7$. $|S_n| = n!$, and $7$ is prime, and if $n<14$ we have only one factor of $7$ and no factors of $49$, so there can't be an isomorphism.

But I'm having trouble with the other direction. By Cayley's Theorem, I know that $\mathbb{Z}_7 \times \mathbb{Z}_7$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_{49}$. I also know that $S_n$ has two factors of $7$ is it is divisible by $49$. But I don't see how to go from there to saying that $\mathbb{Z}_7 \times \mathbb{Z}_7$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$ with $n\ge14$. Does anyone have any hints?

Comment: The group of permutations of, say, $73$ elements has, as a subgroup, the group of permutations of the first $14$ elements.

Comment: Just choose two elements of $S_n$ of order $7$ that commute, e.g., cyclic permutations of distinct sets of $7$ elements of $\{1, \dots, n\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take the subgroup generated by
$$(1234567)$$
and
$$(8\ 9\ 10\ 11\ 12\ 13\ 14)$$
These are both of order $7$ and they commute, so they generate a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_7\times\mathbb Z_7$.

Conversely, if $S_n$ has a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_7\times \mathbb Z_7$, then $7^2\mid n!$, so $n\geq 14$.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry if this is a dumb question, but why is the group generated permutations being isomorphic to Z_7xZ_7 implied by the generators commuting?

Comment: @lightnesscaster Let the elements be $a$ and $b$. The subgroup generated by $a$ and $b$ consists of all elements of the form $a^ib^j$, and $(a^ib^j)(a^pb^q)=a^{i+p}b^{j+q}$ because they commute.

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Comment: @lightnesscaster Sure, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $n\ge14$, you have disjoint $7$-cycles.